# How to create a never ending thread that does not slow the PC

Tags: c#, multithreading, service

I developed a Windows Service in C# that starts 7 threads in OnStart event that call a method to initialize some hardware devices and then enter while loop while waiting for external events from those devices.

The while loop (in each thread) is:

```
            try
            {
                while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0)) { }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
```

The problem is that while the service is started (so, the threads are running), the PC got very slow. How is the best way to do such a loop?

The thread initialization is before the while loop and the thread cleanup is after the while loop.

Comment: The best way is don't loop at all. Show the API of the hardware you are using, there is likely a event that gets raised when data is available that you are overlooking that would let you get rid of the loops entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hardware devices should trigger an interrupt when data arrives and call into an event, which means you shouldn't need to loop in 7 different threads. Instead, once you receive some data from the hardware then start a thread to process that data so the main thread can receive more data. This type of while loop will freeze a thread and if you have 7 on a quad core processor with HT that means you only have one thread left for all the other programs on your PC, which results in slowdown.

Answer (score 3):

Probably you could sleep your thread for some milliseconds after each iteration.

```
try
 {
  while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0)) 
   {
     Thread.Sleep(1000);
   }
 }
 catch
 {
 }
```

Comment: Or even better `while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(1000))`, same effect but puts the pause on the timeout of the `WaitOne`.